# Posture / Prostration in Yemenite Tradition

Tags: tefilla, islam, yemenite-temani

It is related that the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) initially prayed three times a day face to Jerusalem. It is evident that this practice corresponds the Jewish practice.

The Salat prayer in Islam consists of a sequence of recitations associated to a sequence of standing and prostration.

Does anybody know whether Yemenite/Arabic Jews used to pray (or still pray) in a similar form, i.e. alter the position of the body (standing, bowing down, kneeling down, falling on the face etc.).

P.S. This question is motivated by my research of the origins of Islam, but only Jews or Judaists can answer this question. That is why I would very much appreciate an answer.

P.P.S: A negative answer from somebody living or knowing Jemenite practice that none such is related or practiced is also welcome.

Comment: By "a similar form" do you mean "with a sequence of standing and prostration" or do you mean "with _that same_ sequence of standing and prostration"? If the latter, then you'll need to [edit] the question to describe the sequence you mean.

Comment: This question boils down to, "Do Jews bow in ways similar to the Muslims?", which requires knowledge beyond the scope of Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @N.T. could you please re-open this question. It is a question about Judaism, although it comes from outside.

Comment: @msh210 I do not expect the same sequence. This has developed later in Islam anyway. The question is rather whether this is a Jewish tradition or rather a tradition from the prior polytheist Arab religion.

Comment: Sounds like an Islam question. For the record, I  am not a moderator.

Comment: It is a question related to Islam. The classical Islamic answer is that it had been established by Abraham and restored by Muhammad. Little effort inside Islam has been undertaken so far to search for the roots of the prayer in Judaism.

Comment: @Double AA, could you please reopen this question?

Comment: (answering in comment until reopening) All Jewish prayer uses the four positions mentioned: The main prayer is said while standing, but at the beginning and at three other points we bow in a two step bow, first bending the knees or waist and then bowing the head, and after the main prayer there is a prayer said while falling on one's face. The motions used are not the same as in Muslim prayer from what I have seen. The bending of the knees is not a full kneel, and the falling on one's face is performed, in modern times, while seated.

Comment: @Mordechai That's not a great answer, because the questioner is more interested in how Jews prayed back then. Arguably, back then they did actually kneel/bow on the floor in all those cases. Indeed there's no question bending the knees separate from bowing as you described is from the Zohar and is not mentioned by anyone before the 14th century; it's not even in the shulchan aruch. The old sources are generally ambiguous about the floor so there's not going to be a great proof here.

Comment: @DoubleAA you mention that «Arguably, back then they did actually kneel/bow on the floor in all those cases» do you know a source? In general, your answers rather encourage me to assume Jewish practice.

Comment: @Mordechai: Thanks for the answer; in fact, the only Jewish prayer I have shared so far was Birkat Hamazon so I did not even know about present practice.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I fully agree. Better some answer that none, IMHO.